# Cannot Transfer File using scp command for certificate authority

Tags: ubuntu, certificate, vpn, openvpn

So I trying to setup OpenVPN on my Ubuntu 20.04. I am using this online article(https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-setup-a-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-20-04) that was recommended to me to set up a VPN with the Certificate Authority. I am new in Linux and understanding the syntax. I am stuck in this area:

```
scp -v pki/reqs/server.req  krillavilla@camachine:/home/krillavilla/


Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host camachine, user krillavilla, command scp -v -t /home/krillavilla/
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname camachine: Name or service not known
lost connection
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the link {https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-setup-a-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-20-04}i provided. you need two machines in order to create a VPN server and client-server. I trying to do it locally. One machine